# Create a new column in Spark DataFrame using UDF

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a UDF as below -

```
  val myUdf = udf((col_abc: String, col_xyz: String) => {
    array(
      struct(
        lit("x").alias("col1"),
        col(col_abc).alias("col2"),
        col(col_xyz).alias("col3")
      )
    )
  }
```

Now, I want to use this use this in a function as below -

```
def myfunc(): Column = {
    val myvariable = myUdf($"col_abc", $"col_xyz")
    myvariable
}
```

And then use this function to create a new column in my DataFrame

```
val df = df..withColumn("new_col", myfunc())
```

In summary, I want my column "new_col" to be an type array with values as [[x, x, x]]

I am getting the below error. What am I doing wrong here?

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type org.apache.spark.sql.Column is not supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways.

1. Don't use a UDF because you're using pure Spark functions:

```
val myUdf = ((col_abc: String, col_xyz: String) => {
    array(
      struct(
        lit("x").alias("col1"),
        col(col_abc).alias("col2"),
        col(col_xyz).alias("col3")
      )
    )
  }
)

def myfunc(): Column = {
    val myvariable = myUdf("col_abc", "col_xyz")
    myvariable
}

df.withColumn("new_col", myfunc()).show
+-------+-------+---------------+
|col_abc|col_xyz|        new_col|
+-------+-------+---------------+
|    abc|    xyz|[[x, abc, xyz]]|
+-------+-------+---------------+
```

2. Use a UDF which takes in strings and returns a Seq of case class:

```
case class cols (col1: String, col2: String, col3: String)

val myUdf = udf((col_abc: String, col_xyz: String) => Seq(cols("x", col_abc, col_xyz)))

def myfunc(): Column = {
    val myvariable = myUdf($"col_abc", $"col_xyz")
    myvariable
}

df.withColumn("new_col", myfunc()).show
+-------+-------+---------------+
|col_abc|col_xyz|        new_col|
+-------+-------+---------------+
|    abc|    xyz|[[x, abc, xyz]]|
+-------+-------+---------------+
```

---

If you want to pass in Columns to the function, here's an example:

```
val myUdf = ((col_abc: Column, col_xyz: Column) => {
    array(
      struct(
        lit("x").alias("col1"),
        col_abc.alias("col2"),
        col_xyz.alias("col3")
      )
    )
  }
)
```

Comment: Another qq, In 2nd method when I try to pass null instead of "x" as Seq(cols(null, col_abc, col_xyz)), I get an error "error: an expression of type Null is ineligible fo
r implicit conversion". Can you advise please.

Comment: If you have nulls, I'd suggest using the first method. A udf is not necessary here, and would only cause problems.

Comment: Also I can't reproduce the problem on Spark 3.0, even if I put null inside cols.

Comment: In the first method, I am passing the values from a different function which are of type 'Column' - myUdf(col_abc, col_xyz), so I am getting an error found   : org.apache.spark.sql.Column
 required: String

Comment: Also, I want to reuse the "myUdf" multiple times for different variables.

Comment: If you're passing in a column, then you'd need to change the function argument types to Column instead of String. Also you need to remove `col` later in the function.

Comment: 1 more question, how can I add nullable property for the fields within myUdf? I want all the columns, including array and struct to be nullable (nullable = true)